# How to get the difference in different rows within a categories in the below table? PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

i want to ****compute diff**** and  return all the rows that have diff>2

I don't have index column in my table and i am not allowed to add index in my table because it is a temporary table

I am pSQL beginner. Any helps will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: First learn what database you are using MySQL, SQL-server and Postgresql are different databases... please correct your tag

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Comment: I supouse you want to separate diffs by "client" in my answer

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **window functions**: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html

```
create table temp1(
    client integer,
    value integer
);

insert into temp1 values
   (100,2), (100,5), (100,5), (102,2), (102,3);

select client, value, 
       lead(value) over (partition by client order by value) - value as diff
  from temp1
  order by client, value;
```

You can try this at: http://rextester.com/GBKZ11796